# how do I solve for x when it is an exponent on both sides?

Tags: exponential-function

I am given the equation:

5 * 3^x = 2 * 7^x

The text book and everywhere online shows me how to do this when the variable is only on one side or when it can be subtracted/added, not when it is tied to a multiplication.

Of course the latter is going to be on the test and not what is taught in the book.

How am I supposed to edit this to get rid of the two down votes? Was this question already asked? What could've I possibly typed in to get my answer?

Comment: `I know how to take the log of both sides` You may want to give that a second try, since $\log(5 \cdot 3^x) \ne 5 \cdot x \cdot \log(3)$.

Comment: "I know how to take the log of both sides and end up with:

5 * x * log(3) = 2 * x * log(7)".  That ISN'T what you should end up with when you take the logs from both sides.  Taking the logs from both sides *IS* what you should do.  But you should do it correctly; not incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

$5*3^x = 2*7^x$ so

$\log (5*3^x) = \log(2*7^x)$

$\log 5 + \log 3^x = \log 2 + \log 7^x$

$\log 5 + x\log 3 = \log 2 + x \log 7$.

Now just treat those logs as constants.....

Hint:

$x \log 3 - x \log 7 = \log 2 - \log 5$

$x (\log 3 - \log 7) = \log 2 - \log 5$

$x = \frac {\log 2 - \log 5}{\log 3 - \log 7}$.

Comment: If I ended up with log 5 - log 2 = x log 7 - x log 3 after you said "Hint: ..." would it have been wrong? If so, then how am I supposed to know what to move over to which side?

Comment: No that would have been fine. You'd be saying $-A = -B$ instead of $A=B$. Try to think about what equations _mean_ rather than about rules to "move things over".

Comment: That would not have been in the least bit wrong.  It doesn't matter what side you move things over as long as you do it correctly.  If you had $A + Bx = C + Dx$ and *I* did $Bx - Dx = C - A$ and *you* did $A-C = Dx -Bx$ and I continued and got $x(B-D) = C-A$ and you cont. and got $A-C = x(D-B)$ and I concluded $x=\frac{C-A}{B-D}$ and you concluded $\frac {A-C}{D-B} = x$. Which of us is right and which of us is wrong? Well, unless $D=B$ then $\frac {A-C}{D-B} = \frac {-(C-A)}{-(B-D)} = \frac {C-A}{B-D}$ and we are both right and neither wrong. (Of course, if $B=D$ then we were *both* wrong....)

Answer (score 1):

After taking $\log$ on both sides you actually get:
$$\log 5+x\log3=\log 2+x\log 7$$
$$\Longrightarrow x= \frac{\log\frac{5}{2}}{\log \frac{7}{3}}$$

Answer (score 0):

A good start is always to collect the unknown:
$$5=2\cdot\frac{7^x}{3^x}\iff5=2\cdot\left(\frac73\right)^x$$
an then isolate:
$$5/2=(7/3)^x.$$
Now take logarithm 
$$\ln(5/2)=x\cdot\ln(7/3)$$
and arrive in 
$$x=\frac{\ln(5/2)}{\ln(7/3)}.$$